# POST HttpRequestMessage is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a Web API in ASP.NET Core, the method has the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Foo(HttpRequestMessage data)
```

This is the data I am sending to the action:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <DTO
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <field1>1</field1>
            <field2>2</field2> 
        </DTO>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am making the request with Postman where Data is a soap xml message.
The headers' Content-Type:   :"application/xml" 
(also tried : application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

For some strange reason, when I am trying to read this data, I can see the following:
Method: Get
Content: null
Request Url: null
Headers: {{}}

In the Start, I also included XmlFormatters (presuming that this is the source of the problem):

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());                    
        }
    );
```

But it did not help.

I also have another Web Api (for .NET Framework) where I successfully receive HttpRequestMessage parameter.

What is the source of the issue?

Comment: are both .Net and Core apps and code the same?

Comment: The code in both apps in the same except of the Startup where, as I mentioned I tried to put xmlformatters thinking that this might resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core does not handle SOAP requests out of the box. You need to add some middleware to handle the SOAP message. I have used this project previously and it has worked really well:

https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore

There is a detailed walkthrough of how to use the library her:

https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/

Comment: Sorry, I might have not been clear enough. I 've just edited my post providing the sample of the data I am sending.

Answer (score 0):

[Model binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) doesn't work the same way as in the previous versions.

---

So first step was right - you registered XML formatters to allow MVC middleware use it for model binding, as by default only JSON formatter is added.

Next step was also right - you added `Content-Type: application/xml` header to tell a type of content that you send with HTTP POST.

What you should add, is tell the MVC middleware that your data passed in `request body`. This is done by adding `[FromBody]` attribute to the model parameter:

> `[FromBody]`: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the request.

and cause XML formatter will do deserialization internally, you need to update action parameter to type that represents your XML data structure.

Something like this should be in final:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Foo([FromBody] ClassThatRepresentsXMLstructure data)
```

Comment: No, it does not work. If I use [FromBody] I get mediatype exception

Comment: @JoeDoe this exception tells that some another type of formatter is needed. Maybe you will need a custom one for your soap data. Or you need to specify another content type. Try `application/soap+xml`

Comment: I tried application/soap+xml - it does not work. Not sure what kind of other formatter your are talking about.  Please have a look above at the example of the data I am sending